# java- How to find intersection of values in Hashset in loop?

Tags: java

I wrote a program in Java where it retrieves records from a database table and stored them in a hashmap.

The keys and values of them are like the following:

```
Key(represent words)      Values(represent filename)

w1                          file1
w2                          file1
w3                          file2
w4                          file1
w5                          file2
w6                          file1,file2
............
```

The list goes on and on but this is just an idea of how it looks like.As you can see, there's no duplicate for words and they are unique.

Given that I have this hashmap info,I need to find the intersection of the key and it's next key and return the results of the intersection. The idea looks like this:

```
w1∩w2= file1
w2∩w3= empty
w3∩w4= empty
```

........and it keeps going until it reaches the finishes the final pair of keys in the hashmap.

Since the pair of intersection results depends on the number of keys in the hashmap,I am guessing I'll need to use some loop to keep it iterating to return all the results.

Is there a way on how to get the intersection of each subsequent keys and also a way that is optimize regardless the size of the hashmap?

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: When you say ```w1∩w2``` is ```w1∩w3``` not possible? or will you still get the intersection of ```w1``` paired to any other keys?

Comment: What intersection you want ? Intersection of map.get(w1) and map.get(w2) ? or intersection of letters in the w1 and w2 ??

Comment: yes only the intersection of w1 ^ w2 , not w1^w3 not possible

Comment: @AchintyaJha Intersection of the map which will return the results of the path(file), that's all. I need to use word(key) as a reference to find the intersection

Comment: any particular reason you are using `TreeSet`? do you want all keys to be sorted and do not want to preserve insertion order?

Comment: @dkb It doesn't have to be sorted. I'm just giving an example above of how it would look like. The order does not matter,rather than just finding the intersection of key and(key+1) and then key+1 and key+2 and so on

Comment: All in all, it doesn't matter if keys are sorted or not, I just want to know the idea to finding intersection in such situation for my sake of it

Comment: *"the next key*" – `HashMap` doesn't have the concept of "next key". Why don't you use a `LinkedHashMap`, which has predictable iteration order?

Comment: Changed my Hashmap to LinkedHashmap?

Comment: I have a hard time grasping your interpretation of the word "intersection" and what logic you want to use here. As pointed out, since hash map isn't sorted it looks kind of random which keys gets paired together. Also what is the difference between this and your previous question?

Comment: Let's assume it's using LinkedHashMap and the order of words is ordered by the entries added to the map. So in this case, I would just be looking of what is the same filenames that occur in w1 and w2 (intersection). Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a variable that will hold all those intersections. In your loop retrieve 2 keys at a time. Compare each values of the 2 keys and if they are the same add the value to your intersection holder. Repeat the steps until there is no more pairs.

Here is the code.

Add this below your try/catch

```
LinkedHashmap<String, Set<String>> intersectionMap = new LinkedHashmap<>();
if (map.keySet() != null) {
    String[] keys = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.keySet().size()]);
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
        String key1 = keys[i];
        String key2 = keys[i + 1];
        TreeSet<String> interSection = intersection(map.get(key1), map.get(key2));
        intersectionMap.put(key1 + "∩" + key2, interSection);
    }
}
```

Add this helper method. This method will find the intersection of the two sets. This will be the key in solving your problem.

```
public static TreeSet<String> intersection(TreeSet<String> setA, TreeSet<String> setB) {
    // An optimization to iterate over the smaller set
    if (setA.size() > setB.size()) {
        return intersection(setB, setA);
    }
    TreeSet<String> results = new TreeSet<>();
    for (String element : setA) {
        if (setB.contains(element)) {
            results.add(element);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: I use LinkedHashmap instead of Hashmap, it should be the same.

Comment: Mind explaining what the helper method is for? Is it even needed? I need to grasp understanding of your code.

Comment: The helper method is needed since this is how you will find the intersection between two sets.

Comment: You're checking if setA is greater than size of setB?

Comment: It is just an optimization, so that the method will iterate on the smaller sized set. Example if you have ```setA = ['a','b','c']``` and  ```setB = ['x','y']```, the checking will let you iterate ```setB``` instead of iterating on ```setA```. Meaning lesser iteration.

Comment: This line `TreeSet<String> interSection = intersection(map.get(key1), map.get(key2));` there is error on intersection. Where this come from?

Comment: What error will it generate? Did you place the helper method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188792/discussion-between-daredevil-and-mark).

Answer (score 1):

Yet another version with set operations:

```
Map<String>, Set<String>> intersections(Map<String, TreeSet<String>> map) {
    Map<String>, Set<String>> result = new TreeMap<>();

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    words.sort();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size() - 1; ++i) {
        String wordI = words.get(i);
        Set<String> valueI = map.get(wordI);
        for (int j = i + 1, j < words.size(); ++j) {
            String wordJ = words.get(j);
            Set<String> valueJ = map.get(wordJ);

            String word = wordi + "∩" + words[j];
            Set<String> value = new TreeSet<>(valueI);
            value.retainAll(valueJ);
            result.put(word, value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```